# Horizontal scroll to next div (id) (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I got this little script that turns three divs into 'pages'. What i would like to happen is that when you scroll horizontally to the next div, it scrolls to that div and centers it (creating a 'swipe to next page'-effect).
I've not been able to get it to work. I made a little jsfiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/scvyafxf/1/

Hope someone will be able to help!

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var cmdaCarrousels = document.querySelectorAll(".cmda-carrousel");
  for (var i = 0; i < cmdaCarrousels.length; i++) {
    var cmdaCarrouselItems = cmdaCarrousels[i].querySelectorAll(".cmda-carrousel-item");
    if (cmdaCarrouselItems.length > 0) {
      var bolletjes = document.createElement("ul");
      bolletjes.classList.add("cmda-bolletjes");
      for (var j = 0; j < cmdaCarrouselItems.length; j++) {
        var bolletje = document.createElement("li");
        bolletjes.appendChild(bolletje);
      }
      cmdaCarrousels[i].appendChild(bolletjes);
      cmdaIniActiveBolletje(cmdaCarrousels[i]);

    }
  }
})();

function cmdaIniActiveBolletje(deCarrousel) {
  var carrouselContainer = deCarrousel.querySelector("ul:first-of-type")
  cmdaSetNummer(carrouselContainer);
  carrouselContainer.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    cmdaSetNummer(this);
  });
}

function cmdaSetNummer(carrouselContainer) {
  var carrouselWidth = carrouselContainer.offsetWidth;
  var carrouselItems = carrouselContainer.querySelectorAll(".cmda-carrousel-item");
  var carrouselItemFirstWidth = carrouselItems[0].offsetWidth;
  var carrouselItemNormalWidth = carrouselItems[1].offsetWidth;
  var carrouselItemPaddingRightPX = window.getComputedStyle(carrouselItems[0]).getPropertyValue("padding-right");
  var carrouselItemPaddingRight = parseInt((carrouselItemPaddingRightPX.substring(0, carrouselItemPaddingRightPX.length - 2)), 10);
  var scrollPos = carrouselContainer.scrollLeft;

  var hetNummer = 0;
  if (scrollPos < (carrouselItemFirstWidth - (carrouselItemPaddingRight / 2) - (carrouselWidth / 2))) {
    // hetNummer = 0;
  } else {
    var t = 1;
    while (hetNummer == 0) {
      if (scrollPos < ((carrouselItemFirstWidth - (carrouselItemPaddingRight / 2) - (carrouselWidth / 2)) + (t * carrouselItemNormalWidth))) {
        hetNummer = t;
      }
      t++
    }
  }

  var bolletjes = carrouselContainer.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".cmda-bolletjes li");
  for (var b = 0; b < bolletjes.length; b++) {
    bolletjes[b].classList.remove("active");
  }
  bolletjes[hetNummer].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#pag1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#pag2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#pag3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.cmda-carrousel > ul:first-of-type > li {
  min-width: calc(100%);
  height: calc(100vh - 104px);
}

.cmda-carrousel > ul:first-of-type > li:not(last-child) {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.cmda-carrousel > ul:first-of-type > li:first-child {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.cmda-carrousel > ul:first-of-type > li:last-child {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}


/* color dots */

.cmda-carrousel .cmda-bolletjes li {
  background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}


/* color active dots */

.cmda-carrousel .cmda-bolletjes li.active {
  background-color: #e4322b;
}

.cmda-carrousel > ul,
.cmda-carrousel > ul > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* slider container */

.cmda-carrousel > ul:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.cmda-carrousel > ul:first-of-type::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
}


/* slider items */

.cmda-carrousel > ul:first-of-type > li {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}


/* dots */

.cmda-carrousel .cmda-bolletjes {
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cmda-carrousel .cmda-bolletjes li {
  margin: 0 .25rem;
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* carrousel items content container */

.cmda-carrousel .my-content {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="cmda-carrousel">
    <ul>
      <li class="cmda-carrousel-item" id="pag1">
        <div class="my-content">
          <h1>Page 1</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="cmda-carrousel-item" id="pag2">
        <div class="my-content">
          <h1>Page 2</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="cmda-carrousel-item" id="pag3">
        <div class="my-content">
          <h1>Page 3</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/scvyafxf/1/

Comment: what did you tried ? I not see any click handlers here.

Comment: Nah i don't want it to happen on click. When the user scrolls, the next div should auto scroll and center in the screen